# How can I change the textwith for a predefined glossary style?

Tags: glossaries

I would like to change the textwidth for the glossary, or better the predefined glossary style I'm using (to avoid a line break in the glossary header) without changing it for the entire document. is that possible?

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[ngerman,british,USenglish]{babel} %lädt die deutsche Sprache
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[acronym,toc,shortcuts]{glossaries}


\makeglossaries

\renewcommand*\entryname{Name}
\renewcommand*\descriptionname{Bedeutung}
\setglossarystyle{long3colheader}


\renewcommand*{\glsnamefont}[1]{\bfseries #1}%

\newglossaryentry{AT}
{
        name=Außentemperatur,
        description={gemessene Außentemperatur}
}

\newglossaryentry{ALT}
{
  name=Auslegungstemperatur,
  description={die minimale Außentemperatur, bei der die Heizlast des Gebäudes  \SI{100}{\percent} gedeckt ist}
}


\begin{document}

\clearpage
\printglossary[type=main,title={Bedeutung}]

\newpage


 \gls{AT} 
 \gls{ALT} 


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

To avioid the line break in the header, you can adjust the widths of the columns:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[ngerman,british,USenglish]{babel} %lädt die deutsche Sprache
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[acronym,toc,shortcuts]{glossaries}


\makeglossaries

\renewcommand*\entryname{Name}
\renewcommand*\descriptionname{Bedeutung}
\setglossarystyle{long3colheader}
\addtolength{\glspagelistwidth}{0.6cm}
\addtolength{\glsdescwidth}{-2.5cm}


\renewcommand*{\glsnamefont}[1]{\bfseries #1}%

\newglossaryentry{AT}
{
        name=Außentemperatur,
        description={gemessene Außentemperatur}
}

\newglossaryentry{ALT}
{
  name=Auslegungstemperatur,
  description={die minimale Außentemperatur, bei der die Heizlast des Gebäudes  \SI{100}{\percent} gedeckt ist}
}


\begin{document}

\clearpage
\printglossary[type=main,title={Bedeutung}]

\newpage


 \gls{AT} 
 \gls{ALT} 


\end{document}
```

Comment: merci @samcarter; but is there a way to extent the entire width of the predefined style to gain more space?